# Changing the parameter in sql query of ASP.NET page - with button_click event, sql query in every button click

Tags: asp.net, sql, iterator, logic, code-behind

I have a ASP.NET page which have details in below manner.

```
 Date       OfficerID    DutyID
 25-NOV-13  2           666
 26-NOV-13  2           666
 27-NOV-13  2           666
 28-NOV-13  2           666
 29-NOV-13  2           666
 30-NOV-13  2           666
 01-DEC-13  2           666
 02-DEC-13  2           523
```

The above is being populated in gridview through below code snippet

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
string sqlQuery = "select * from duty_rota where duty_date between sysdate and sysdate+18";


using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
        {
             using (OracleDataAdapter ODA = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
             {
                  ODA.Fill(table);
             }
        }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
         Response.Write("Not Connected" + ex.ToString());
   }

}

//DropDownList1.DataSource = table;
//DropDownList1.DataValueField = "";

GridView1.DataSource = table;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Now I also have a **previous button** which should output the same page but with sql query slightly changed

```
select * from duty_rota where duty_date between sysdate-18 and sysdate;
```

and with every button click the date parameters should be decreased by 18, i.e with 1st previous button click query will be

```
sysdate-18 and sysdate
```

with 2nd click

```
sysdate-36 and sysdate-18
```

with 3rd click

```
sysdate-54 and sysdate-36
```

and so on...

Please help me how could I acheieve it , I was trying to implement it with a variable associated with Previous buttons button click event which would change with every subsequent click. But I am not really able to accomplish it. Can anybody please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write below code to handle dynamic query on previous and next button click event :

```
protected void PrevioseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sqlQuery = this.GenerateQuery(false);
    this.BindGrid(sqlQuery);
}

protected void NextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sqlQuery = this.GenerateQuery(true);
    this.BindGrid(sqlQuery);
}

private string GenerateQuery(bool isNext)
{

    if (ViewState["fromDate"] == null && ViewState["toDate"] == null)
    {
        ViewState["fromDate"] = isNext ? "sysdate+18" : "sysdate-18";
        ViewState["toDate"] = isNext ? "sysdate+36" : "sysdate";
    }
    else
    {
        var from = ViewState["fromDate"].ToString().Replace("sysdate", string.Empty);
        var to = ViewState["toDate"].ToString().Replace("sysdate", string.Empty);

        int fromDay = 0;
        int toDay = 0;

        if (from != string.Empty)
        {
            fromDay = Convert.ToInt32(from);
        }

        if (to != string.Empty)
        {
            toDay = Convert.ToInt32(to);
        }

        if (!isNext)
        {
            fromDay = fromDay - 18;
            toDay = toDay - 18;
        }
        else
        {
            fromDay = fromDay + 18;
            toDay = toDay + 18;
        }

        from = "sysdate";
        to = "sysdate";
        if (fromDay > 0)
        {
            from += "+" + fromDay;
        }
        else if (fromDay < 0)
        {
            from += fromDay.ToString();
        }

        if (toDay > 0)
        {
            to += "+" + toDay;
        }
        else if (toDay < 0)
        {
            to += toDay.ToString();
        }

        ViewState["fromDate"] = from;
        ViewState["toDate"] = to;
    }

    var sqlQuery = "select * from duty_rota where duty_date between " + ViewState["fromDate"] + " and "
                            + ViewState["toDate"];

    return sqlQuery;
}

private void BindGrid(string sqlQuery)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
            {
                using (OracleDataAdapter ODA = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    ODA.Fill(table);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Not Connected" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: It works very good. Idea of using view state is actually awesome.

Comment: just a quick question - can you please help me with next button query please. I am new this Viewstate/Session stuff. I mean the query will be incremental with sysdate, -- DUTY_DATE Between SYSDATE and SYSDATE +18
SYSDATE +18 and SYSDATE.

Comment: ok. I will update my answer once I create sample code for this.

Comment: I found one issue , when I click on the Next button is at first populating date between SYSDATE and SYSDATE+18, but ideally it should show data between SYSDATE+18 and SYSDATE+36, can you please help how could I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

On the button click event, try this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable(); 
string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
if (Session["sysdate"] == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["sysdate"].ToString()))
    Session["sysdate"] = "-18";
else
    Session["sysdate"] = "+ " + (Convert.ToInt32(Session["sysdate"]) - 18).ToString();
string sysdate = Session["sysdate"].ToString();
string sqlQuery = "select * from duty_rota where duty_date between sysdate " + sysdate + " and sysdate+18 " + sysdate;

using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
        {
             using (OracleDataAdapter ODA = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
             {
                  ODA.Fill(table);
             }
        }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
         Response.Write("Not Connected" + ex.ToString());
   }
}

GridView1.DataSource = table;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Me thoughts an ObjectDataSource control would perfectly provide you with a solution...however then I realized that your pagesize varies!

In such a case you need to have your pagination to be disassociated with the gridview. Meaning pagination should be separate and your data which needs to be displayed in the grid view need to be separate. They may have something like a master-child relationship. It means you'd need separate db calls for fetching "each".

You pagination part could be rendered by a gridview or a data list view.

However, if the pagesize on the gridview is always constant you need read this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13963/Implement-Paging-using-ObjectDataSource-with-GridV